# Kendo ComboBox not populating on REST GET

Tags: combobox, kendo-ui, schema, getjson, kendo-combobox

Trying to display "COLUMN_NAME" text in combobox. Here is the successful '200' response with parsed string from the browser:

`[{"COLUMN_NAME":"Account","DATA_TYPE":"char"},"COLUMN_NAME":"Address","DATA_TYPE":"char"},...}]`

Here is my js:

```js
var dataSourceCustomers = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "http://127.0.0.2:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Wks/WW/MapServer/exts/RestSOE/Search%20Parameters?searchType=CUSTOMER&f=",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            type: 'GET'
        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: ["COLUMN_NAME","DATA_TYPE"],
    }
});

dataSourceCustomers.read();
```

The combobox however is blank. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the definition of `schema.data` that you define it as an array and this is not supported. In addition and according with you example of JSON you don't need it.

And in the ComboBox you define where on each item of the array is where you have the field for the Combo.

It should be like:

```js
var dataSourceCustomers = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "http://127.0.0.2:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Wks/WW/MapServer/exts/RestSOE/Search%20Parameters?searchType=CUSTOMER&f=",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            type    : 'GET'
        }
    }
});

$("#combo").kendoComboBox({
    dataSource   : dataSourceCustomers,
    dataTextField: "COLUMN_NAME"
})
```

BTW: Your example looks like JSON and not JSONP. Is it JSONP?

Comment: Thanks so much. A bit of an oversight with the array. I changed the jsonp to json and all worked fine. One thing I'm interested in doing is setting the initial value (so it shows in placeholder) on the combobox based on another combobox/dropdownbox and then filtering the array. Case: if combobox1 value selected is 'customers', then set combobox2 selected item to 'address' and combobox3 selected value to 'street'. (Can you do this in a dropdownlistbox?). Next step was to explore filtering the array results from the (clientside) combobox so I could take advantage of the cascading function.

Comment: Check `cascadeFrom` option (http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/combobox#configuration-cascadeFrom) in combobox. You have a demo here :  http://demos.kendoui.com/web/combobox/cascadingcombobox.html. If you model the data conveniently it should work for what you want